# Continuous form height problems

Tags: ms-access, ms-access-2007

My continuous form seems to have a mind of its own when it comes to height. Put simply; it returns a maximum of three rows.

```
Header height: 0,674cm
Detail height: 0,661cm
Footer height: 1,501cm
```

This makes it look like this:
[image]

This seems perfectly fine at first sight. When opening the form in form view however it looks like this:

[image]

Now I know these problems are quite regular, but here is what I have already tried:

```
- Auto resize to 'No'
- Set the height with code
- Use the move command. (Couldn't get that to work)
- Changed all the 'can grow/shrink' settings to yes
- allowed scroll bars
- played with the 'keep together' option
- Changed the border styles
```

Unfortunately I am out of options at the moment.

**EDIT:** Query only returns 3 rows here in this example.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From what I can see you are not using the form as maximized, therefore the move command should work.

This is what I use in VBA :

```
DoCmd.MoveSize , , 20 * 556, 12 * 556
```

To resize my forms. Add this to your Form_Load event.

It is pretty straighforward a call, but you can check [its documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff197394(v=office.15).aspx) if you like...

Comment: Why thank you, it seems I was using the move command with incorrect syntax. Solved!